# Disturbed frequently during interview. How can I deal with it?

Tags: interviewing

I have applied for senior developer position in a small organization. My resume was shortlisted and I got an interview call.

After the interview started, it was disturbed multiple times. The interview panel contained 2 interviewers. After we started, a person came inside the room and served coffee to all of us.

A bit later, another person comes and had quick chat with one of the interviewers, the went. A couple of other similar disturbances occurred during the interview process.

I do not feel good about this interview process. Luckily I have been shortlisted for second round.

I am expecting these kind of disturbances in the second round also. How can I deal with these disturbances and keep concentrating on selling myself during this interview process?

Comment: sounds like a possible test situation, sounds like you passed. in what way did the interruptions bother you that you want to "deal with them"?

Answer (score 14):

Relax. Just let the distractions happen like water off a duck's back. Handle it professionally, just as you would handle interruptions on the job. Consider it part of the background noise unless someone is speaking, and then take that opportunity to pay attention and respond if you're spoken to, in a way that demonstrates your people skills vs. your technical skills. I.e. consider it an opportunity to show your warmth as well as your competence.

Answer (score 9):

More than anything, this is your opportunity to sell yourself and you should consider it as one. Second interviews, in my experience, focus less on the technical screening and more on "how will this guy fit into our company" and this is actually where interruptions can help.

- show how unflappable you are and that an interruption isn't a distraction.
- you're someone who expects interruptions and you'll deal with them on the job as smoothly as you are in this interview.
- show how you don't lose your train of thought by getting back on topic when the interruption is over.

Above all **do not look annoyed** or the least bit put off by the interruption. You're a flexible and adaptable guy who won't let something silly bother you.

And when the interruption happens, smile. Genuinely smile. You want even the people doing the interrupting feel like they are welcome around you.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities here:

a) this is how the office works on a daily basis

b) it's a subtle test to see how well you handle interruptions

Either way, if you want the job your only option is take it in stride. If you don't work well that way maybe now is a good time to withdraw your application.

When I first read the question I thought it was the interviewER not liking the interruptions. If you make it to the HR department your options can then extend to a sign on the door and "GTFO" to anyone who doesn't read it. Pointing weapons at the intruder is, unfortunately, usually discouraged in today's workplace.